# Facebook application is not working

Tags: facebook, fbml

We have a legacy facebook application based on FBML. 
Till 2 days ago the application was running successfully. 
Suddenly the application stopped running.

Our application's settings was set to FBML, however when 
I switch to iframe I can see my app but in a non working state. 
It was working fine with the FBML settings

I want to run the application for a months period based on FBML. 
So that within this period we can switchover to iFrame.

I understand that FBML will become unsupported post Jan 1, 
but I still should have a month right!

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0):

My FBML app stopped working around this day too. The problem is that they switched to the new auth system, where instead of sending the fb_sig HTTP parameters to identify the user and verify that the request came from Facebook, they now send one single parameter called signed_request. Which language/library are you using to interface with Facebook? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ for more details on this new signed_request parameter.

Regarding FBML.  FBML apps should still work until June 1, 2012.  On January 1 they just won't allow new apps to be FBML.